# How to do fetch select for @ManyToMany load via spring-data?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data, many-to-many

I try load roles of the user with `User` entity via `@ManyToMany` for auth, but I get Exception.

```
ERROR: column user0_.role_id does not exist
```

I just started to learn spring data. Please help me fix this issue. Thank You.

User entity:

```
@Entity(name = "users")
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "role_id")
    private int roleId;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_id_role_id"
            ,
            joinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id",
                            nullable = false,
                            updatable = false)
            },
            inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id",
                            nullable = false,
                            updatable = false)
            }
    )
    private List<Role> authorities;

    @Column(name = "account_non_expired")
    private boolean accountNonExpired;

    @Column(name = "account_non_locked")
    private boolean accountNonLocked;

    @Column(name = "credentials_non_expired")
    private boolean credentialsNonExpired;

    @Column(name = "enabled")
    private boolean enabled;
...
```

And Role entity:

```
@Entity(name = "user_role")
public class Role implements GrantedAuthority {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "role")
    private String role;
...
```

My PostgreSQL schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_role (
  id   SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  role VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
  id                      SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  username                VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  password                VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  account_non_expired     BOOLEAN            NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE,
  account_non_locked      BOOLEAN            NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE,
  credentials_non_expired BOOLEAN            NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE,
  enabled                 BOOLEAN            NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE
);

CREATE TABLE user_id_role_id (
  id      SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  role_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (role_id) REFERENCES user_role (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id)
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error indicates that you don't have property role_id in table user.
You have this property in entity:

```
@Column(name = "role_id")
private int roleId;
```

but when you create table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
  id                      SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  username                VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  password                VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  account_non_expired     BOOLEAN            NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE,
  account_non_locked      BOOLEAN            NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE,
  credentials_non_expired BOOLEAN            NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE,
  enabled                 BOOLEAN            NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE
);
```

you don't have property role_id.

Just remove property roleId from User entity and it should work :)

Comment: looks like my brain some overloaded. Thank You! It's best answer :)